# Docker D:// external drive volume mounting

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to run a very simple `docker-compose` using some paths into my external `D:` drive for volumes on Windows 11:

```
services:
  radarr:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/radarr:latest
    container_name: radarr
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    volumes:
      - D:\blb\config\radarr:/config
      - D:\blb\media\cinema:/cinema
    ports:
      - 7878:7878
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The folders are created inside of `D://` as expected, but no files are written into those folders, they just stay empty.

- `D:\blb\config` is always empty, but when I run `ls config` from within the container, it contains config files;
- Similarly, `D:\blb\cinema` has files I put inside it, but when I run `ls cinema` from within the container, there's nothing I there.

I've tried replacing back slashes with front slashes, I've tried using a double front slash after the disk name, but to zero avail.

I've also tried modifying the permission at the root of the `D://` drive. I added a permission for **users** to write and modify data, but this made no difference either.

P.S. The config does persist when I `compose down` and `up` again, so they must be stored elsewhere by default.